# Align text on the side and top of other text css

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve this using css?

[image]

This is what I've tried:

```html
<label style="position:absolute; top:-15px; margin-left: 20px; font-size:18px"">R$</label>
    <label style="margin-left:45px; font-size: 35px;>54.133</label>
    <label style="position:absolute; top:-15px;>48</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I think you dont even need that, just a little bit beautifuler

### Origin

<sup>$</sup>234 <sup>07-04</sup>

### After add style

```
<p style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: lighter; color: rgba(57, 152, 27, 0.97);"><sup style="font-size: 15px;">$</sup>234<sup style="font-size: 15px;">07-04</sup></p>
```

Please use downbelow style, dont mix html and style, that's terrible

```css
 
    .normal{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: rgba(57, 152, 27, 0.97);
    }
    .upper{
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<p class="normal">
    <sup class="upper">$</sup>234<sup class="upper">07-04</sup>
</p>
```

Comment: That's the problem. I need the text aligned on the top of the bigger text and not higher than.

Comment: @Perozzo try again, now is OK

Comment: Thank you very much for a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

```css
label{
  font-size:20px;
}

label sup{
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<label><sup>R$</sup>54.133<sup>73</sup></label>
```

Use superscript tag

```
<label><sup>R$</sup>54.133<sup>73</sup></label>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp

Comment: This do not align the text as the image on the question.

Comment: Still do not answer my question because the alignment isn't the same as I asked.

Comment: Just add white space or margins to have exact result.

Answer (score 2):

This is the css solution to achieve the [superscript](https://sbpoley.home.xs4all.nl/webmatters/superscripts.html).Just try this:

```html
    <label style="position:relative; top:-0.5em; margin-left: 20px; font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-size:18px"">R$</label>
    <label style="margin-left:45px; font-size: 35px; font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'" runat="server" id="lblBalancePeriod">54.133</label>
    <label style="position:relative; top:-0.8em;">48</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<span class="currency">
  <span class="prefix">R$</span>
  54.133
  <span class="suffix">73</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.currency {
  color: green;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.prefix, .suffix {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Shown in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pl3ODb).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox:

```
<div class="container">
  <label class="sign">R$</label>
  <label class="number">54.133</label>
  <label class="decimal";>48</label>
</div>

<style>
  .container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  label.sign{
    align-self: flex-start;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  label.number{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  label.decimal{
    align-self: flex-start;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

More [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)